# Exclude a trailing dot in hashtag using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to convert hashtags in a text into some `<a href="/tag/...">...</a>` links.

The code I am trying to use is

```
text.replace(/#([^#\s@]+)/ig, "<a href='/tag/$1'>#$1</a>")
```

But it fails when the testing text is as below

```
blah blah #example.
```

The trailing dot will be matched and the resulting link will become

```
blah blah <a href='/tag/example.'>#example.</a>
```

It is not the result I want. 
Are there any ways to exclude the trailing dot but keep the dots in between each hash tag? Like `blah blah #keep.the.dot.in.between #example2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/quvhfky8/

```
text.replace(/#([^#\s@]*[^.\s])+/ig, "<a href='/tag/$1'>#$1</a>")
```

The above should give you what you want.

it'll ignore the trailing period on "#hello."  but capture "#hello.whatever"
 it'll also exclude any final dot, so for instance "#hello.whatever." will capture as though the final dot weren't there "#hello.whatever"

Here's a link to show you it in action: http://regexr.com/3ao8l
Regexr is a great site to test out patterns!

If this isn't what you wanted please comment and I'll try to accommodate you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
'blah blah #this.is.example.'.replace(/#([^#\s@]*[^.])/g, "<a href='/tag/$1'>#$1</a>")
"blah blah <a href='/tag/this.is.an.exampl'>#this.is.example</a>."
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can leverage the `word boundary` anchor for this case using `#([^#\s@]+)(?=$|\b)` regex. Also, I'd rather use `"` double quotation marks (I just prefer this style):

```js
var re = /#([^#\s@]+)(?=$|\b)/g; 
var str = 'blah blah #example.  blah blah #keep.the.dot.in.between #example2';
var subst = '<a href="/tag/$1">#$1</a>';
var result = str.replace(re, subst);
document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<div id="res"/>
```